# Access String value in enum without using rawValue

Tags: string, swift, enums, swift2

I would like to replace my global string constants with a nested enum for the keys I'm using to access columns in a database.

The structure is as follows:

```
enum DatabaseKeys {

    enum User: String {
        case Table = "User"
        case Username = "username"
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Each table in the database is an inner enum, with the name of the table being the enum's title. The first case in each enum will be the name of the table, and the following cases are the columns in its table.

To use this, it's pretty simple:

```
myUser[DatabaseKeys.User.Username.rawValue] = "Johnny"
```

But I will be using these enums **a lot**. Having to append `.rawValue` to every instance will be a pain, and it's not as readable as I'd like it to be. How can I access the String value without having to use `rawValue`? It'd be great if I can do this:

```
myUser[DatabaseKeys.User.Username] = "Johnny"
```

Note that I'm using Swift 2. If there's an even better way to accomplish this I'd love to hear it!

Comment: What kind of object is ```myUser```? A Dictionary or your own object with a subscript?

Comment: @AndyIbanez It could be a simple dictionary, or a PFUser in my case as I'm using Parse

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While I didn't find a way to do this using the desired syntax with enums, this is possible using structs.

```
struct DatabaseKeys {

    struct User {
        static let identifier = "User"
        static let Username = "username"
    }

}
```

To use:

```
myUser[DatabaseKeys.User.Username] = "Johnny"
```

Apple uses structs like this for storyboard and row type identifiers in the WatchKit templates.

Answer (score 18):

You can use CustomStringConvertible protocol for this.

From documentation,

> String(instance) will work for an instance of any type, returning its
>   description if the instance happens to be CustomStringConvertible.
>   Using CustomStringConvertible as a generic constraint, or accessing a
>   conforming type's description directly, is therefore discouraged.

So, if you conform to this protocol and return your rawValue through the description method, you will be able to use String(Table.User) to get the value.

```
enum User: String, CustomStringConvertible {

    case Table = "User"
    case Username = "username"

    var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

var myUser = [String: String]()
myUser[String(DatabaseKeys.User.Username)] = "Johnny"

print(myUser) // ["username": "Johnny"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Though having to use `String` to initialize a string is just as inefficient. :P I'd actually rather use `rawValue` than wrapping it up in `String()`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with enums of type Int?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [callAsFunction](https://www.donnywals.com/how-and-when-to-use-callasfunction-in-swift-5-2/) (New in Swift 5.2) on your enum that conforms to String.

```
enum KeychainKey: String {
   case userId
   case email
}

func callAsFunction() -> String {
    return self.rawValue
}
```

usage:

```
KeychainKey.userId()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with custom class:

```
enum Names: String {
    case something, thing
}

class CustomData {
    subscript(key: Names) -> Any? {
        get {
            return self.customData[key.rawValue]
        }

        set(newValue) {
            self.customData[key.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }

    private var customData = [String: Any]()
}

...

let cData = CustomData()
cData[Names.thing] = 56
```

**Edit:**
I found an another solution, that working with Swift 3:

```
enum CustomKey: String {
    case one, two, three
}

extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    subscript(key: CustomKey) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[key.rawValue as! Key]
        }
        set {
            self[key.rawValue as! Key] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var dict: [String: Any] = [:]
dict[CustomKey.one] = 1
dict["two"] = true
dict[.three] = 3
print(dict["one"]!)
print(dict[CustomKey.two]!)
print(dict[.three]!)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this for all enums that inherit from a base class?

Comment: Does this only for for uses of the enum as a dictionary key?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use `User` as dictionary key instead of `String` (`User` is `Hashable` by default) it would be a solution.

If not you should use yours with a nested struct and static variables/constants.